# Minimum ShapeLength using arcpy.Polyline?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, line

Please, i am creating lines using arcpy.array(point1,point2) --> arcpy.Polyline...but my ArcGIS create lines only with shape lenght 0.0002 and longer...why ?? I want to create also shorter lines cause my points are very close to each other. Is it something with arcpy.env.XYTolerance or Resolution? Thanks for your advices...

Answer (score 1):

the tolerance is linked with your feature class and not with the processing tools. XY tolerance won't help you to go below this tolerance (see ArcGIS help caption)

> If the x,y tolerance is less than twice the output geodataset's x,y
>   resolution value, an x,y tolerance of two times the x,y resolution
>   will be used

You can set the precision of your feature class when you create a feature class manually, but I don't think that it is possible to do it in arcpy. If you need to create many feature classes in a script, the best workaround I know is to create a feature dataset manually and create your new feature classes into it: the new feature classes will have the same XY tolerance as the feature dataset).

Comment: For processing tools, you use the env module to set XYTolerance, ie. arcpy.env.XYTolerance. When creating a featureclass, arcpy can set the XYTolerance via the Spatial Reference object.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting the Geometry's Spatial Reference before inputting the coordinates. The SR has its own XYTolerance and XYResolution, that you can view or change. I had a very similar issue when working with Lat/Long data as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was like post from "klewis". I had my FC in WGS84 and there couldnt be shorter line than 0,0002  (I dont know why). In my script , when the geometry were created, I project these FCs to UTM34N . So I changed these steps (first project empty FC and then fill it with geometry) and it works for me. Sorry for my English and Thanks for your advices :)